# UICollectionView Header Dynamic Size according to its contents and margins

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I have a `UICollectionView` where my header is of type `UICollectionReusableView`. Now I have multiple items in the header which may lead to variability in the size of the header. These items also do have padding/contraints. How exactly should I address this?

Comment: It just should resize if you have autolayout enabled

Comment: Well, I have constructed everything programmatically, and do have the auto layout. But while returning the size in `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`. What should I return in the height? And please help me out here, I am confused big time

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet. There is no such thing as a self-sizing header view. You just have to measure / calculate the desired size of the header view based on its contents, yourself, and use that as the result of `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`.

The typical approach, if you're configuring the contents of the header view with constraints, is to set up a model header view with the desired contents and constraints and call `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize` to get the autolayout engine to tell you the resulting size.

Comment: Exactly, there's nothing as self sizing. But the second part that you mentioned can you help me more in there code wise. I am honestly unable to get my head around. I know this is the approach. Where exactly should I be calling `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`. I really can use your help to understand matt